# Save numbers of PFObjects to multiple rows

Tags: ios, arrays, parse-platform, save

I am having the database o parse server with 200 items. I would like to refresh a NSNumber count column on Parse according to the count of each Array located also on Parse. I tried to do it with query but it returns me wrong numbers and also do not stop and still refreshing NSNumbers in the rows on Parse.

```
-(IBAction)refresh:(id)sender{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Prah"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            NSMutableArray *title = [objects valueForKey:@"Title"];
            NSMutableArray *subtitle = [objects valueForKey:@"FavoritedBy"];
            for (int i = 0; i < [title count]; i++){
                NSUInteger arrayLength = [[subtitle objectAtIndex:i] count];
                NSLog(@"JAK:%lu", (unsigned long)arrayLength);
                for (PFObject *object in objects){
                    [object setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:arrayLength] forKey:@"FavoritedCount"];

                    [object saveInBackground];
                    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                }}
            NSLog(@"%@", objects);
            NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[objects count]);

        } else {
            [query cancel];
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];


        }
    }];



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a limit on your `PFQuery` object, the default is 100.

```
query.limit = 10000;
```

Documentation of `PFQuery`

> limit
>
> A limit on the number of objects to return. The default limit is 100,
>   with a maximum of 1000 results being returned at a time.
>
> @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger limit Discussion Warning: If
>   you are calling findObjects with limit = 1, you may find it easier to
>   use getFirst instead.
>
> Declared In PFQuery.h

See more at [Parse Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/limit)